# SSRS: how to display each value of the multi-value Parameter in a TextBox after page break based on that multi-value Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, page-break, multivalue

This query is Based on the example in this Link https://www.sqlshack.com/using-multi-value-parameters-in-ssrs/.

1. Let us assume that I have several Job Titles in the multi-value Parameter:

- Accountant
- Accounts Manager
  (...)
- Chief Executive Officer

[image]

2. Now, if I select several job titles at a time, their Label will appear on top of the title as follows:

[image]

My question is: if I apply Page Break based on those multi-value parameters, **how do I display Parameter Value per Page Break instead of all of them combined by the `Join` function**?

- Page 1 should be "*Employee Detail report:* **Accountant**"
- Page 2 should be "*Employee Detail report:* **Accounts Manager**"
  (...)
- Page N should be "*Employee Detail report:* **Chief Executive Officer**"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the JobTitle descriptions returned in your dataset, then you can add a group in your report's table which groups by JobTtitle (if you don't already have one).

Now add a header row to your group and in there you can drop your JobTitle field into the text box.

Comment: Thanks @Alan let me try that and will revert back to you. Cheers